# CSS dropdown menu extends only on the left side

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position

my problem is I would like to have a menu which is going to expand slide by slide, but now it is only expand on one place and not under that menu item I hovered...

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" id="HyperLinkLabelEditor" runat="server"><span >
            <asp:Label  ID="LabelEditor" runat="server" Text="Stammdaten" />
        </span></a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkIngredients" runat="server" Text="Zutaten" NavigateUrl="#" /></li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkUnits" runat="server" Text="Einheiten" NavigateUrl="#" /></li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkEditAttribute" runat="server" Text="Attribute" NavigateUrl="#" /></li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkUsers" runat="server" Text="Benutzer" NavigateUrl="#" />
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkRolls" runat="server" Text="Rollen" NavigateUrl="#" /></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkUser" runat="server" Text="Benutzer" NavigateUrl="#" /></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperWorkflowCoredata" runat="server" Text="Workflow" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="HyperLinkLabelCustomersAndProjects" runat="server"><span >
            <asp:Label  ID="LabelCustomersAndProjects" runat="server" Text="Kunden" />
        </span></a>
            <ul class="submenu sdt_box">
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkNewCustomer" runat="server" Text="Neuer Kunde" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkContracts" runat="server" Text="Verträge" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkPublishing" runat="server" Text="Ausleiten" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="HyperLinkLabelLinkWorkflow" runat="server"><span >
            <asp:Label CssClass="LabelLinkWorkflow" ID="LabelLinkWorkflow" runat="server" Text="Workflow" />
        </span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="HyperLinkLabelSearch" runat="server"><span >
            <asp:Label  ID="LabelSearching" runat="server" Text="Suchen" />
        </span></a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkRecipes" runat="server" Text="Rezepte" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkEncyclopedia" runat="server" Text="Lexikon" NavigateUrl="#" /></li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkArticle" runat="server" Text="Artikel" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="HyperLinkLabelLinkQS" runat="server"><span >
            <asp:Label CssClass="LabelLinkQS" ID="LabelLinkQS" runat="server" Text="QS" />
        </span></a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkQAOverview" runat="server" Text="Rezeptüberblick" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkQARarelyUsedUnits" runat="server" Text="Rezepte mit selten verwendeten units" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkQAWrongResolution" runat="server" Text="Rezepte mit Bildern in falscher Auflösung" NavigateUrl="#" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="HyperLinkRelease" runat="server"><span >
            <asp:Label CssClass="LabelLinkWorkflow" ID="LblRelease" runat="server" Text="Veröffentlichung" />
        </span></a></li>
        <li id="ListItemLogin" runat="server"><a href="#" id="HyperLinkLabelLogins" runat="server"><span >
            <asp:Label  ID="LinkLabelLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" />
        </span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and now the css part:

like

```
.container
{
     width: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;  
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.toggleMenu
{
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav
{
    list-style: none; /**zoom: 1; additional styles */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.nav:before, .nav:after
{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.nav:after
{
    clear: both;
}

.nav ul
{
    list-style: none;
    width: 9em;
}
.nav a
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav li
{
    position: relative;
}
.nav > li
{
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #104336;
}

.nav li span span, .nav li a
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: White;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    -o-transform: scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.nav li span
{
}
.nav:hover li span span, .nav:hover li a
{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
}
.nav li span span:hover, .nav:hover li a:hover
{
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    background: rgba(105,105,105,0.4);
}
nav li:hover li a:hover
{
    background: #95A9B1;
}
.nav > li > .parent
{
    background-image: url("/Context/Pictures/Menu/downArrow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
.nav > li > a
{
    display: block;
}
.nav li ul
{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px; /*nice effect -> left:40%; maybe before" and "after" */
}

.nav li li.hover ul
{
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.nav li li a
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 1px solid #175e4c;
}
.nav li li li a
{
    z-index: 200;
    border-top: 1px solid #176451;
}
.nav li li li a:hover, .nav li li a:hover
{
    border: 1px solid;
}
a#HyperLinkLinkQSOverview:hover, a#HyperLinkLinkQS:hover
{
    width: 800px;
    border: 1px solid;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 950px )
{

    /*.nav:hover, ul:first-child li:hover */
    /*, .nav li li.hover ul*/
    .nav > li:hover > ul
    {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /*  height:300px;     background-color:Black;    overlapping menu*/ /*another menu */
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        position: fixed;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
        transition: all 0.4s linear;
        padding-bottom: 15%; /*.nav > li.hover > ul {}*/
    }

    .nav li li.hover ul
    {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
        transition: all 0.4s linear;
    }


}
```

I Think the problem is here, Iam sure that position "fixed" is not correct, but for me it is the only way to have the menu to be over the main area(where the content is) and to collapse slide by slide(and not the entire menu).
If I remove position:fixed and z-index the menu is going to expand the entire menu and the menu is going to move the entire down on mouseover and moving up on mouseout.... 
code problem i think:

```
    .nav > li:hover > ul
{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
    padding-bottom: 15%; 
}
```

the wrong result is here :

http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=108ioi8&s=8#.UvfOV4Vn3O4

I mean the menu is nice, but it is only collapsing and expanding on the left side (same position), i should be under the hovered menu item...

I dont know what to do anymore ...
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to change

```
.nav > li:hover > ul
```

from position:fixed to absolute?

Comment: maybe you have overflow:hidden in your header?

Comment: I think we are on the correct way, it is expanding but it is hidden inside the ".header" I thought it is enough to use "z-index" to make clear that the menu item is going to be over everthing... the result looks at the moment like : [link](http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ingw47&s=8#.UvfjfYVn3O4) it doesnt matter how high the valu of z-index(inside .nav > li:hover > ul)  it is not going to be over that.headerand than the menu display like in the link in current comment...but ty for help

Comment: thank you overflow was correct, that was the solution. But there is another errorthe submenu items appear a few milliseconds on the very left(after mouse hover) kind of flickering- thank you so far :) - it comes from the very left flickering to the correct position –

Comment: I think it has something to do with left:-9999px and  transitions you have applied to elements...

Comment: ty for that,  but now I can not center that menu, I tryed padding-left:50% and padding-right:50% (also with margin...) , text-align:center but the menu is still floating on the left... I rhink I need something like clear:both ?!... or where/what can be the problem for that ?

Comment: Do you have margin:auto applied to the menu?